# eating before kiddush

Tags: shabbat, zemanim, kiddush, eating

Is there any time in the early morning on Shabbat in which I can eat and drink something without any question of it being considered eating before davening and kiddush?  For example, at 3, 4, or 5 o'clock in the morning?  Is there a certain time before netz or alot hashachar in which it's definitely acceptable to eat and drink on Shabbat morning?  Also, does the type of food matter?  As a second point, what if I wake up early during a weekday?  Is there a point at which I can definitely eat and it's not considered eating before davening?  is there a point I cannot begin to eat unless I first daven?  Is there ever a time at which I'd have to stop eating and drinking and wait until it's time to daven to eat or drink again?  Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: related/dupe? http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/20661/759

Answer (score 1):

There are actually 2 variables here in play, one if it shabat or a weekday, and second if the person is a man or a women.

on a weekday a women can eat anything before the morning prayers. for a men it depends, maran says one can drink water, coffee and tea even with sugar while ashkenazim are more lenient on this.

on shabat the same rule applies for man, while for women it depends if she usually prays shaharit on shabat or not.

if yes she can eat the same as men, if not she is already obligated by kidush, therefore you can't eat until you do kidush. note that you don't need to wait, you can do kidush at 7 am and eat your breakfast.

the time for this is the same as the time for praying, all the while it is still night you can eat, as soon morning starts, meaning as soon as the obligation to do shaharit begins you'll need to fulfill your obligations before eating.

Comment: Why is a woman allowed to eat before morning prayers, particularly if she is planning on praying them?

Comment: Thank you, @Avraham  When is the obligation for Shacharit?  Dawn, the earliest time for tallit and tefillin, or sunrise?  Whatever time that is, is it permissible to eat and drink before that time on both Shabbat and weekdays?  Also, is it okay to start to eat right before that time or does eating and drinking have to start at an earlier time (like how on fast days you can't start eating past a certain time before the fast actually starts)?  Also, does eating and drinking that was started at an appropriate time have to stop at a certain time on Shabbat and weekdays?

Comment: @doubleaa women doesn't have the obligation to do shaharit. women need to do only one prayer a day, not necessarily shaharit, you can do only minha for example, or both

Comment: @ana again, on weekdays you can eat whenever you feel like, don't worry, when there's a public fast you only need to refrain from eating when the fast starts, not before. it is considered night until alot ashahar. do you really need to eat that early?

Comment: @Avraham That's not true according to most poskim, including the Shulchan Aruch who does not distinguish between genders regarding Tefilla. See http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/11888/759 Do you want to back yourself up with some sources?

Comment: @Avraham Prior to the time for prayer in general, one cannot have a settled meal for a half hour before the time of the mitzva. This applies in the early morning prior to a fast day just like any other day. See http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/20665/759 Do you have a source to back your assertions up?