# time for shacharit and eating before this time

Tags: zemanim, kiddush, shacharis-morning-prayer, eating

When is the obligation for Shacharit?  Is this what is considered the morning?

Is it dawn (alot hashachar), or the earliest time for tallit and tefillin, or sunrise (netz), or the latest time for tefilla according to whatever source a person follows?

I'm interested in an answer to this on its own, and I'm also interested to know because someone said it's permissible to eat and drink before that time on both Shabbat and weekdays, without first davening on either of these days, and without making kiddush on Shabbat.  Is that accurate?

Thank you.

Comment: Hi Ana and a belated welcome to Mi Yodeya. You've asked several similar questions, most recently http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/21867/eating-before-kiddush. The question of when the obligation for shacharit is seems separable from that one. Could you [edit](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/posts/21875/edit) this question to be more distinct from it? Also, please consider [registering](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/login) your account, which will [give you access](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) to more of the site's features.

Comment: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1381/whats-the-best-way-to-disentangle-these-questions-about-rising-early-washing

Comment: took out most of it, hope it's okay now.  (i asked a similar question here because the follow up comment i asked about this wasn't answered on another question and i'm really trying to get this all straight.)  thanks.

Comment: @ana You should consider being more patient before asking new questions. The poster you wrote your follow up comment to might not have been back to his computer in the few hours before you posted this. Moreover, I don't know why this is such a pressing issue that you need to keep asking right away; if this is a practical issue for you then you should speak to a rabbi and NOT rely on anything you see here, particularly when unsourced, because we are just a bunch of strangers.

Comment: @DOubleAA, i will try for more patience.  to answer why i asked similar questions, it's because based on some responses that addressed only certain aspects of my very first question here, without acknowledging the other parts, i thought maybe i wasn't clear as to my intended question and what specifically i was trying to figure out, so i kept trying to get another part of the question answered, and another, and another, so i wouldn't only have pieces of information, but a whole understanding of the halacha.

Answer (score 1):

The Kitzur Shulchan Aruch in Ch 8 states:

> 1. **Starting from *Amud HaShachar*** - since one could in emergency pray then - one is forbidden from starting any work or business dealings or embarking on a journey before one davens.
> 2. And one may not eat or drink... even coffee or tea with sugar and milk... however for medical purposes one may. Similarly if one cannot concentrate in davening without having eaten one may eat or drink beforehand.
> 3. Some say that the [above] prohibition against eating and drinking applies even if one awoke at **midnight**... however one may eat or drink to give one energy to learn Torah.
> 4. **Water** or tea and coffee **without sugar and milk** is permitted before prayers, even after Amud Hashchar... even on Shabbat, though one hasn't heard Kiddush yet...